# Value of type 'NSSet' has no member '_' - Unable to Access attributes through NSSet

Tags: xcode, swiftui, core-data, nsset

I have a core data model set up with 3 entities: Exercise, ExerciseSet, and Workout. It's set up so that Exercise and ExerciseSet have a one to one relationship and Workout and ExerciseSet have a one to many relationship. I am trying to access the properties within ExerciseSet via Workout but when I run this code:

```
struct WorkoutView: View {
@State var workout = Workout()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Sets in Workout: \(workout.exerciseSets.count)")
        
        ForEach(Array(arrayLiteral: workout.exerciseSets), id: \.self) { e in
            Text("Exercise Name: \(e.exercise.exercisename), Reps: \(e.reps), Weight: \(e.weight)")         
        }
```

I get the following error

```
Value of type 'NSSet' has no member 'exercise'
Value of type 'NSSet' has no member 'reps'
Value of type 'NSSet' has no member 'weight'
```

These properties all exist when I call them outside of the workout and workout.exerciseSets.count returns as expected.

Here are the definitions of each entity:

```
extension Exercise {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Exercise> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Exercise>(entityName: "Exercise")
    }

    @NSManaged public var exercisename: String
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var musclegroup: String?
    @NSManaged public var exerciseSet: ExerciseSet?

}

extension Exercise : Identifiable {

}
```

```
extension ExerciseSet {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ExerciseSet> {
        return NSFetchRequest<ExerciseSet>(entityName: "ExerciseSet")
    }

    @NSManaged public var dateCompleted: Date
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var reps: Int16
    @NSManaged public var weight: Int16
    @NSManaged public var exercise: Exercise
    @NSManaged public var workout: Workout?

}

extension ExerciseSet : Identifiable {

}
```

```
extension Workout {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Workout> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Workout>(entityName: "Workout")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var notes: String?
    @NSManaged public var workoutDate: Date
    @NSManaged public var workoutMuscleGroup: String?
    @NSManaged public var workoutName: String?
    @NSManaged public var exerciseSets: NSSet
    
    public var exerciseSetArray: [ExerciseSet] {
        let set = exerciseSets as? Set<ExerciseSet> ?? []
        return set.sorted {
            $0.dateCompleted < $1.dateCompleted
        }
        
    }

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for exerciseSets
extension Workout {

    @objc(addExerciseSetsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToExerciseSets(_ value: ExerciseSet)

    @objc(removeExerciseSetsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromExerciseSets(_ value: ExerciseSet)

    @objc(addExerciseSets:)
    @NSManaged public func addToExerciseSets(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeExerciseSets:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromExerciseSets(_ values: NSSet)

}

extension Workout : Identifiable {

}
```

Is there something that I am missing in order to be able to access the attributes within ExerciseSet through Workout? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSSet` in Swift has no idea of the underlying type.

Replace `Array(arrayLiteral: workout.exerciseSets)` with `workout.exerciseSetArray`.

It's mandatory to convert `NSSet` to native `Set<ExerciseSet>` to be able to access the attributes. Or - easier - declare `exerciseSets` as `Set<ExerciseSet>`. Core Data works pretty well with native Swift types.